# Send SMS and outbound calls only during certain hours with Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

How would we do this with Twilio 
We need to add code that allows messages / calls only to be sent from 9 am New York time to 9 pm New York time

message can be sent from 9:00am - 8:45 pm. (this will give a 15 minute buffer to clear out the queue
Message can not be sent from  8:46 pm til 8:59 am  New York time

Answer (score 0):

There are past blogs that take advantage of JavaScript libraries to help with routing based on date/time of day. You can also apply this to SMS response behavior.

[Using Twilio Functions to Add Custom JavaScript Code in Studio Flows](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/06/custom-javascript-twilio-functions-code-studio-flows.html)